# DataGridView error when set DataSource

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I got an error when run datagridview.DataSource = dataView;
dataview is correct. I can see data inside it when I debug program.

I got next error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any Ideas?

code:

```
this.datagridview = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
```

...

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
  StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(retString);
  XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings);
  ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
  DataView dataView = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

dataView is not null. I am able to view it when debug

Comment: What error do you get?  What platform are you using? (WinForms ASP.Net, WPF, Silverlight?)  What is `dataView`?

Comment: what platform are you coding for? asp? silverlight? wpf? winforms? the answer you get could depend on the platform.

Comment: it is WinForms. DataGridview and DataView

Comment: What's the stack trace in the exception?

Comment: C# Windows Form .Net application

Comment: Stack trace:  at frmCustomers.frmCustomer.btnDeposits_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e in E:\Asp.Net\slnBanking.frmCustomers\frmCustomer.cs:line100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all you code in the same method, or is the initialization of the `DataGridView` in a `InitializeComponent` method?

If it's in a `InitializeComponent` method, make sure that your other code is called after that method has been called. Check that if you've got a constructor for your `Control` that it calls `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: the InitializeComponent is called when the form is loaded and the dgvDeposits is called long after that.  I do not have a constructor in the method for the DataGridView control.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `datagridview` variable is `null`.

Comment: It still means that the `datagridview` field is `null`.  Where is this code?  Can you check `datagridview` in the debugger?

Comment: the DataGridView is null when I set it to null.  I don't see a problem with setting the control to null.  The stack trace shows: at frmCustomers.frmCustomer.btnDeposits_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Asp.Net\slnBanking.frmCustomers\frmCustomer.cs: line 100.     Line 100 is where I set the control value to null.