# DataGridView.Datasource = null; ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm confused as to why setting the datasource of a datagridview control to null, would cause an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  Thanks in advance

```
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "deposits"))
    {
        oDeposit.DepAmt = Convert.ToDouble(xmlReader.GetAttribute("depamount"));
        oDeposit.DepDate = Convert.ToDateTime(xmlReader.GetAttribute("depdate"));
        oDeposit.DepositId = Convert.ToInt32(xmlReader.GetAttribute("depid"));

        oCustomer.addDeposits(oDeposit);
        **dgvDeposits.DataSource = null;**
        dgvDeposits.DataSource = oCustomer.Deposits;            
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `dgvDeposits` is not `null`? It might be that you are just barking up the wrong tree. I've never worked with `DataGridView` though and it might really be the implemented behaviour to throw an exception if you pass `null` to the setter.

Comment: I agree with yas4891 suggestion - check with debugger if `dgvDeposits` is not null in line you've marked. There is nothing wrong with setting `DataGridView.Datasource = null` - I've decompiled it's setter and it doesn't throw any exception if `Datasource` is null. Maybe you're wired with some additional event, like `DataSourceChanged`, where the exception is thrown?

Comment: there is no add'l event for the DataGridView.  The exception is thrown on when I set the value to null.  I beleive the problem lies somewhere with the DataGridView not be initialized as an object.  But Initializecomponent() is called when the form loads and before the exception.  There are references to the datagrid view in the Initialize components.

Comment: As the others have said - this should not be throwing an error. You will need to provide your whole class to get an answer - I don't believe it can be answered with the current information.

Comment: @Susan: Try calling another method on the DGV to check if it's that one that's not initialized properly or if it's just the `DataSource` property that fails. So for example, try adding the row `dgvDeposits.MultiSelect = false;` before the line setting the `DataSource`. If that fails, try looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) and comparing with your own code to make sure it's initialized properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this instead of setting DataSource to null:

```
dgvDeposits.DataSource = typeof(Deposit);
```

Please check following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834806/datagridview-error-when-set-datasource) it might have an explanation for your exception.

Comment: I don't have a 'typeof' Deposit. I looked over your reference but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @Susan, of course You don't have type Deposit. It is example, I am sorry I didn't clarify that. Guess it should be typeof(whatever_type_is_oCustomer.Deposits) - if it is a List<T> then use T. When You set typeof(some_type) to set DataGridView DataSource, basically you say: "i will store instance(s) of something but there is no data at the moment". However in most cases You will not get an exception when setting DataSource to null. I did and I had to use typeof. I am sorry i didn't help You, guess You will have to provide us with more code.

Comment: I have no idea what this is doing.. why does setting the type of the object to the datasource her problem?

Comment: @sksallaj, what exactly you don't understand? Her problem or why proposed solution helps solve her problem? Why it solves her problem is explained in my comment.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't read your comment section. Sorry about that. Typically solutions on stackoverflow are edited multiple times based on clearing up any confusions in the comment section. Not saying you have to do it, it's my fault for not reading it. I'm upvoting this because this helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I know I'm new to this, but I had the same type of problem. I found that creating a DataTable using the Columns in the DataGridView then setting the table as the DataSource fixes the problem.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DepAmt", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("DepDate", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("DepositId", typeof(int));
dgvDeposits.DataSource = dt;
```

This [site](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable) is what I referenced.